# How to disable setOnItemClickListener?

Tags: android

I've defined `setOnItemClickListener` for my `View` object and I need to disable during some calculations in the application. How to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
yourView.setOnItemClickListener(null);
```

Comment: and how to enable it again?